# global php field in views (drupal 7)

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views

I am unable to get the Global Php field view to work in Drupal 7.

I can get the preview to output what I want, but once I hit the endpoint it no longer is rendering as it does in the preview.

Using the following to test with:

```
<?php
print_r($row->title);
?>
```

Content shows in the preview pane. But not on the endpoint. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Endpoint:**

[image: Endpoint]

**Preview Pane:**

[image: Preview Pane]

My objective is to output the title of a node with hopes of tweaking it once I can get it populating in the endpoint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mu'menYassin - Where? Can you provide the code.

Comment: I updated my description. Data is showing up in preview fine, just not on the page.

Comment: What are you using for the display?  Looks like a JSON output, is that from views, from services, or some other source?

Comment: @acrosman - It is from views from my understanding. Sorry, is there an easy way to confirm this? I am fairly new to Drupal.

Comment: Check to see if you have the services views module running (if so see https://www.drupal.org/node/2135553 for ideas), or the views_json module.  Also if you haven't already check Drupal's internal lots to see if its reporting anything (Reports->recent log messages).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve by adding the following in the **Value code** section when configuring the field.

```
return $row->title;
```

And the following in the **Output code** section:

```
<?php
print $value;
?>
```